# AnalogWrite problem

Tags: analogwrite

I have connected DRV8835 with 2 DC motors with 11 power supply. Arduino nano.

When I for loop like i from 0 to 1024 for analogWrite(i,Motor1) for the DC Motor1 it's accelerating from 0 to 200 and it's stopping. When I becomes 250 it's starting at higher speed. When it becomes 500 it's stopping again. And 550 we have our power again.

Now I tried to run analogWrite(1000, ***) but it's not working. When I change the value from 1000 to 1005 it's not working again. But at 1024 we have the maximum speed and it is working?

```cpp
 #define LEFT_PWM 9
 #define RIGHT_PWM 10
 #define LEFT_DIR 5
 #define RIGHT_DIR 6

void setup() {
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LEFT_DIR, HIGH);
  analogWrite(LEFT_PWM, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`analogWrite` has the following prototype

```
void analogWrite(uint8_t, int);
```

which means that its first parameter has `[0, 256)` range and follows the rules of modulo arithmetic, with `256` as the modulo. If you supply arguments outside of `[0, 256)` range, they will be interpreted `% 256`. `1000` is the same as `232` (`1000 % 256 == 232`), `500` is the same as `244`, `550` is the same as `38` and so on.

This is not fully consistent with the symptoms you describe (if your description is accurate), which might imply that something else is a factor here. Are sure you are using your DRV8835 in `PHASE/ENABLE` mode (pin 11 pulled high)?

Comment: The pin MOD was the real problem. Soldered it to VCC with a wire and problem is solved. Before that the motors behavior was very random.